# Using tf() function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to input this transfer function in matlab, but I can't figure out how because it has both positive and negative exponents.

[image]

If I do `H = tf([1],[1 1 1 1],0.1,'variable','z^-1')` I almost get it, but I can't figure out how to add the positive `z` to the bottom. I'm trying to use this `H` to plot the poles and zeros with `pzmap(H)`.

Comment: I've never used `tf` before, but can't you simplify your transfer function and use `H(z) = 1 / (z^-1 + 1 + z^-2 + z^-3 + z^-4)` instead?

Comment: Yeah I should probably do that, I multiplied by Z because I'm new to the z-transform and thought I needed to do that to get the Zero in the numerator by setting Z = 0 along with getting the poles.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid negative exponents, we can multiply both the denominator and the numerator by `z^3`:

```
H = tf([1 0 0 0 0],[1 1 1 1 1],0.1,'variable','z')
```

Or divide its by `z`

```
H = tf([1],[1 1 1 1 1],0.1,'variable','z^-1')
```

Comment: I don't want to avoid negative exponents, I want to mix and match positive and negative exponents. The H(z) I posted is the one I'm trying to get, whereas the tf() I posted doesn't quite achieve it because it's missing a +z^1 in the denominator.

Comment: I am afrad we cannot do this without analitical rearraging. But if it is possible, it should be like `H = tf({[1],0},{[1 1 1 1],[0,1]},0.1,'variable',{'z^-1','z'})`. I have no access to matlab now. Thus, I cannot check this.

Comment: Ah, I get this error:  The "Variable" property must be set to one of the strings 's' or 'p' for continuous-time systems, and to
one of the strings 'z', 'q', 'z^-1', or 'q^-1' for discrete-time systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can create

```
z = tf('z', 0.1)
```

and then create any transfer function you want, e.g.

```
H = z / (1 + z + z^-1 + z^-2 + z^-3)
```

However, Matlab automatically adds additional pole-zero pairs at `z=0`, to make the transfer function `H` contain only `z` and no `z^-1`. Therefore, you will see multiple poles at `z=0` instead of only one. Unfortunately I haven't found a solution to stop Matlab from doing that...

Comment: I have no idea why, but this produced: H =
 
              z^7
 /
  z^7 + z^6 + z^5 + z^4 + z^3

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to as a transfer function is actually called DSP representation due to their implementation properties. In that every power of z is a unit delay. Hence, you have to use the [`filt`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/filt.html). In this representation z terms should have nonpositive powers hence if you factor out one z from the denominator and cancel out you get

```
H = filt(1,[1,1,1,1,1])
```